# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): ,

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm fairly sure my update code is incorrect too, also if someone could tell me how to implement a phone number and datae of birth into a table that would be great. Really struggling to get everything going.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_FORENAME = "name";
    private static final String COLUMN_SURNAME = "Surname";
    private static final String COLUMN_UNAME = "uname";
    private static final String COLUMN_PASS = "pass";
    private static final String COLUMN_DOB = "D.O.B";
    private static final String COLUMN_CONTACTNO = "contact_number";

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static final String TABLE_CREATE ="create table contacts (id integer primary key , forename text ," +
            " surname text , uname text , pass text , D.O.B integer ,contact_number integer )";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        this.db = db;

    }

    public void  insertContact(Contact c) {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        String query = "Select * from contacts";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();

        values.put(COLUMN_ID, count);
        values.put(COLUMN_FORENAME, c.getForename());
        values.put(COLUMN_SURNAME, c.getSurname());
        values.put(COLUMN_UNAME, c.getUname());
        values.put(COLUMN_PASS, c.getPass());
        values.put(COLUMN_DOB, c.getDOB());
        values.put(COLUMN_CONTACTNO, c.getContactNo());

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public String searchPass(String uname) {
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "Select uname,pass from "+TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        String a, b;
        b = "not found";
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                a = cursor.getString(0);

                if(a.equals(uname)){
                    b = cursor.getString(1);
                    break;
                }
            }
                    while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return b;
    }

    public boolean updateData(String uname, String pass, String contactNo ){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_UNAME, uname);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_PASS, pass);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_CONTACTNO, contactNo);
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "uname = ?", new String[] { uname });
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String query = "Drop table IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(query);
        this.onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to remove dots in date of birth field, i.e. change `D.O.B` to simple `dob`

Comment: You need to change DB version or uninstall the app completely after modifying the  DB columns or any DB related changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query and save your date of brith in String where you need just type cast it

```
private static final String TABLE_CREATE ="CREATE TABLE contacts ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, forename TEXT," +
        " surname TEXT, uname TEXT, pass TEXT, DOB TEXT, contact_number INTEGER )";
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying! I'm now running into this android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contacts has no column named surname (code 1): , I undestand it's telling me theres no column named surname but I can't find where it should be, as in I thought it was in the correct place.

Comment: You are initializing COLUMN_SURNAME string as COLUMN_SURNAME = "Surname"; instead of COLUMN_SURNAME = "surname";

Comment: Yeah your right @matthew Just change S to s because while creating table your using surname and you are trying to get value using Surname so correct it and run again :)

Comment: I changed that and added the comments as suggested but the surname error is still there. Error inserting surname=qweqw contactNo=null forename=qwe dob=null pass=111 id=3 uname=qwee
                                                                                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contacts has no column named surname

Comment: You just uninstall the application and clean build and install again try once if error still there inform me

Comment: if its work for you acppt my answer and upvote my answer Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I added a new Emulator and still running into the same error? How do you uninstall and re install the applcaition.

Comment: Just increase DB version by 1 i.e if  version is 1 do it 2 like DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

Comment: I've tried both uninstall and reinstalling and changing the database version and still running into errors regarding the Columns

Comment: do one thing first uninstall your application and then change your database name and re build and try keep DATABASE_VERSION =1 ok

Comment: Nope, I set it up to uninstall on launch in the edit configuration setting but still get the error (1) table contacts has no column named contactNo, Error inserting surname=qwee contactNo=null forename=qwee dob=null pass=1111 id=0 uname=qwee

Comment: can you email your code to nikhoney27@gmail.com i will look at it and revert you back soon coz your code is right